# how to do OHEM(online hard example mining) on keras

Tags: python, keras

Recently, i try to do OHEM by keras. Have anyone done this on keras ?  my idea as follows:

```
step1 : get the losses of 100 samples each batch during the FP(forward propagation) stage.
step2 : sort the losses of 100 samples by desc
step3 : use top-k losses during the BP(Backpropagation) stage.
```

however, i can't find the api, so i view the source code and found out some relevant codes as follow.
- the code location is in keras/engine/training.py at 888 lines

```
       # Compute total loss.
        total_loss = None
        for i in range(len(self.outputs)):
            if i in skip_indices:
                continue
            y_true = self.targets[i]
            y_pred = self.outputs[i]
            weighted_loss = weighted_losses[i]
            sample_weight = sample_weights[i]
            mask = masks[i]
            loss_weight = loss_weights_list[i]
            output_loss = weighted_loss(y_true, y_pred,
                                        sample_weight, mask)
            if len(self.outputs) > 1:
                self.metrics_tensors.append(output_loss)
                self.metrics_names.append(self.output_names[i] + '_loss')
            if total_loss is None:
                total_loss = loss_weight * output_loss
            else:
                total_loss += loss_weight * output_loss
        if total_loss is None:
            if not self.losses:
                raise RuntimeError('The model cannot be compiled '
                                   'because it has no loss to optimize.')
            else:
                total_loss = 0.
```

the total_loss is a tensor hold all samples ' loss. And Keras use the train_function with the total_loss to train and update parameters. its' code in keras/engine/training.py at 1003 lines.

```
    def _make_train_function(self):
        if not hasattr(self, 'train_function'):
            raise RuntimeError('You must compile your model before using it.')
        if self.train_function is None:
            inputs = self._feed_inputs + self._feed_targets + self._feed_sample_weights
            if self.uses_learning_phase and not isinstance(K.learning_phase(), int):
                inputs += [K.learning_phase()]

            training_updates = self.optimizer.get_updates(
                self._collected_trainable_weights,
                self.constraints,
                self.total_loss)
            updates = self.updates + training_updates
            # Gets loss and metrics. Updates weights at each call.
            self.train_function = K.function(inputs,
                                             [self.total_loss] + self.metrics_tensors,
                                             updates=updates,
                                             **self._function_kwargs)
```

So i just replace the total_loss  with the top-k loss. it may work. so i add two lines code behind the total_loss

```
import tensorflow as tf
total_loss = tf.nn.top_k(total_loss, k=40)
```

the whole code as follows.

```
# Compute total loss.
total_loss = None
for i in range(len(self.outputs)):
    if i in skip_indices:
        continue
    y_true = self.targets[i]
    y_pred = self.outputs[i]
    weighted_loss = weighted_losses[i]
    sample_weight = sample_weights[i]
    mask = masks[i]
    loss_weight = loss_weights_list[i]
    output_loss = weighted_loss(y_true, y_pred,
                                sample_weight, mask)
    if len(self.outputs) > 1:
        self.metrics_tensors.append(output_loss)
        self.metrics_names.append(self.output_names[i] + '_loss')
    if total_loss is None:
        total_loss = loss_weight * output_loss
    else:
        total_loss += loss_weight * output_loss
if total_loss is None:
    if not self.losses:
        raise RuntimeError('The model cannot be compiled '
                           'because it has no loss to optimize.')
    else:
        total_loss = 0.
#total_loss = 0.
# Add regularization penalties
# and other layer-specific losses.
for loss_tensor in self.losses:
    total_loss += loss_tensor
# modify by cxt get top-k loss
import tensorflow as tf
total_loss = tf.nn.top_k(total_loss, k=40)
```

however, it show the error as follows. the reason is the code run during the model.compile stage. there is no data. How can i get the top-k loss ?

```
  File "/home/cxt/softwares/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 921, in compile
    total_loss = tf.nn.top_k(total_loss, k=40)

  File "/home/cxt/softwares/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 1998, in top_k
    return gen_nn_ops._top_kv2(input, k=k, sorted=sorted, name=name)

  File "/home/cxt/softwares/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py", line 2502, in _top_kv2
    name=name)

  File "/home/cxt/softwares/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 768, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)

  File "/home/cxt/softwares/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2338, in create_op
    set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)

  File "/home/cxt/softwares/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1719, in set_shapes_for_outputs
    shapes = shape_func(op)

  File "/home/cxt/softwares/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1669, in call_with_requiring
    return call_cpp_shape_fn(op, require_shape_fn=True)

  File "/home/cxt/softwares/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 610, in call_cpp_shape_fn
    debug_python_shape_fn, require_shape_fn)

  File "/home/cxt/softwares/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 676, in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl
    raise ValueError(err.message)

ValueError: Shape must be at least rank 1 but is rank 0 for 'TopKV2' (op: 'TopKV2') with input shapes: [], [].
```

Comment: How did you call `model.compile` on your code?

Comment: i create a model at the beginning. by follows. 
```
model = Sequential()
model.add(.....), model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['mse', 'accuracy'])@Anthony Kong

Answer (score 1):

The method I used before for OHEM is writing your own data generator. This generator makes samples first and use current model to select top-k samples with largest loss. The code of generator would be something like below.

```
def generate_topk(model):
   all_samples = get_samples() 
   all_samples_prediction= model.predict(all_samples)
   losses = loss(all_samples_prediction, all_samples_groundtruth)
   topk_samples = get_topk(all_samples, losses)
   yield topk_samples, topk_samples_groundtruth
```